# Erlang dialyzer on windows

Tags: windows, erlang, elixir, dialyzer

I am on a Windows 10 machine. I installed Elixir through chocolatey; this installs Erlang 18. How do I install dialyzer? Is the console app a unix only thing?

Comment: @zxq9 is correct but forgot to mention that dialyzer is included in the Erlang 18 release which elixir uses. The problem he attacks is how to find it on windows, not a trivial question. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The names on Windows match Windows conventions. Looking in a Windows installation I have:

```
C:\Program Files\erl7.1\bin\dialyzer.exe
```

This should be what you are looking for. You may want to add it to your path. I honestly can't remember Windows details for the life of me, so I tend to put the full install path to a particular version's `bin/` in a script (batch file, whatever).

Developing directly on Windows tends to be a bit of an uphill battle, imo. It tends to be *much* easier to do development on a *nix first, and after you have your code figured out test your system on Windows and then write a starter/installer or build a Windows release.